# C# double into MySql db double not working

Tags: c#, mysql, double

I'm converting an webshop system to an another system with C#. This is from DB to DB with some convertion between.

I have this code in C#:

```
Double proPriceTmp = Double.Parse(productPrice);
Double realPrice = ((proPriceTmp / 121) * 100);

string insertProduct = "INSERT INTO `" + ocPrefix + "product` ( `product_id`, `model`, `quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `image`, `manufacturer_id`, `shipping`, `price`, `tax_class_id`,`date_available`, `weight`, `weight_class_id`, `length`, `width`, `height`,`length_class_id`,`subtract`,`minimum`,`sort_order`,`status`,`date_added`,`date_modified`,`viewed`) VALUES ('" + product_id + "', @param_model, '" + product_quantity + "', '" + stock_status_id + "', '" + image + "', '" + manufacturer_id + "', '" + shipping + "', '" + realPrice + "', '" + numericUpDown1.Value + "', '" + date_available + "', '" + product_weight + "', '" + weigth_class_id + "', '" + product_length + "',  '" + product_width + "', '" + product_height + "', '" + length_class_id + "', '" + substracting + "', '" + minimum + "', '" + sort_order + "', '" + status + "', '" + product_created + "', '" + product_modified + "', '" + viewed + "')";
MySqlCommand cmdInsertProduct = new MySqlCommand(insertProduct, connOc);
cmdInsertProduct.CommandText = insertProduct;
cmdInsertProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_model", product_name);
cmdInsertProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdInsertProduct.Dispose();
```

This are the values of the price variables ( thanks to the debugger ):

```
productPrice = "1,20000";
proPriceTmp = 1.2;
realPrice = 0.99173553719008256;
```

But the price in the DB is `0.0000`. I've already tryed inserting the info by hand, and that worked ( with that long number ), so that should work.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `points` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_available` date NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So does anybody knows why this isn't working like it supposed to do? Even a little push in the right direction is enough...

**EDIT**

As questioned, here is the value of `insertProduct`. As you can see, is the price there right...

```
"INSERT INTO `oc_product` ( `product_id`, `model`, `quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `image`, `manufacturer_id`, `shipping`, `price`, `tax_class_id`,`date_available`, `weight`, `weight_class_id`, `length`, `width`, `height`,`length_class_id`,`subtract`,`minimum`,`sort_order`,`status`,`date_added`,`date_modified`,`viewed`) VALUES ('51', @param_model, '999999999', '7', 'data/old/letter_trein.jpg', '0', '1', '0,991735537190083', '11', '2013-06-09', '600,000', '1', '0,000',  '0,000', '0,000', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2013-01-09 12:26:02', '2013-10-24 10:23:47', '0')"
```

Comment: Wow, all this without using a parameterized query?

Comment: What is the value of `insertProduct`

Comment: Do you mean the insert is successful with no errors but only price field remains 0?

Comment: @jim, indeed. no errors

Comment: @Mathlight try it with some other simple non-zero value like 1. If successful, then try some decimal value with various decimal separators like "." and ","

Comment: @Steve, i use paramaterized query's for the descriptions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you treat every values as they were a string. In reality when you need to write a numeric field you don't use single quotes around the value. For example, when inserting the value for the `product_id` field you should not use quotes around it. All this mess could be avoided if you use a parameterized query.

This will leave the work to interpreter your values to the Framework code and you don't have to worry about how to represent them correctly inside a string (Not to mention the whole Sql Injection problem) and your `insertProduct` string will be far more readable.

You have already one parameter in your query, extend that to EVERY value.
But pay attention to the numeric values. For example 'product_id' variable should be a number not a string.

```
string insertProduct = "INSERT INTO `" + ocPrefix + "product` ( `product_id`, `model`, " + 
                       "`quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `image`, `manufacturer_id`, " + 
                       "`shipping`, `price`, `tax_class_id`,`date_available`, `weight`, " + 
                       "`weight_class_id`, `length`, `width`, " + 
                       "`height`,`length_class_id`,`subtract`,`minimum`,`sort_order`," + 
                       "`status`,`date_added`,`date_modified`,`viewed`) " + 
                       "VALUES (@pid, @param_model, @qty, @stk, @img, @mid, @ship, " + 
                       "@price, @num, @date', @weight,@classid, @length, @width," + 
                       "@height,@lenid,@sub,@min, @sort,@status,@created,@modified,@view)";
 MySqlCommand cmdInsertProduct = new MySqlCommand(insertProduct, connOc);
 cmdInsertProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", product_id);
 cmdInsertProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_model", product_name);
 ......
```

After this point I think you could have other problems caused by the NOT NULL fields that doesn't have a DEFAULT expressed. I think you should add them to your query

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But why didn't it work before then?

Comment: @Mathlight decimal separator? :)

Comment: @jim, as Rowland Shaw menthoid, it was indeed the decimal seperator :P

Comment: And this is the one of the two reasons why I always use a parameterized query. The insert command is clear, the parsing of a double/date/string for the database engine is a job to pass to the framework code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running in a European(?) locale, that uses the comma `,` as a decimal separator - in the SQL string, you've got `'0,991735537190083'` instead of `'0.991735537190083'`. Now, you *could* change to using an overload of `ToString()` on your `realPrice` to specify the locale to use, or you could change to parameterising the whole query, which would also guard against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Aha, i'm indeed European. And as Steve mentiod, the parameterising of the query did indeed the trick. Thanks for the explanation :D